# Prevent scrolling to bottom of page when using hash URL only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scroll, anchor

I have a parallax website, in which all different sections are accessible via anchor tags in navigation. It works fine when I am on the home page, but when I am trying to access these sections from an external page navigation(thankyou page down below), I land on the appropriate section momentarily but then the page scrolls to the bottom. I have tried a few things, but I cannot exactly pinpoint what's causing it, or how to prevent it from happening.

Home page with sections- http://www.gwcconferences.com/
Navigation via hamburger menu on top-right of header here- 
http://www.gwcconferences.com/thankyou.html

Also, it works fine for the first item in navigation- "Meetings"

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't think there's a way around this - the page renders as it is is loaded, so until the anchor you want has been rendered, the browser will show the top of the page, then it will zoom down.

Comment: Is there a way I can land on these specific sections without using hash URLs? Oh, and do you know how does the meetings one works fine?